# Rails API Server RSpec test always returns empty JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, testing, rspec

I have a problem with testing my Controllers. All tests are working fine, the Controllers are basic CRUD, but one #index action always returns an empty JSON body. I've tried everything and ran out of ideas, so maybe you can help me.

**Here is my Code**

**Controller**

```
class CarUsersController < ApplicationController

def index
  @car_users = CarUser.all

  render json: @car_users
end
```

**Migration**

```
class CreateCarUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :car_users do |t|
      t.integer :car_id
      t.integer :owner_user_id
      t.integer :rental_user_id
      t.integer :service_user_id
      t.string :role

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Model**

```
class CarUser < ApplicationRecord

  rolify
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :owner_user
  belongs_to :rental_user
  belongs_to :service_user

  validates :role, presence: true
  validates :role, acceptance: { accept: ['owner', 'rental', 'service'] }

end
```

**RSpec Factory**

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :car_user do |p|

    p.owner_user_id { Faker::Number.digit }
    p.driver_user_id { Faker::Number.digit }
    p.service_user_id { Faker::Number.digit }
    p.car_id { Faker::Number.digit }
    p.role 'owner'

    end
end
```

**And the RSpec-Test**

```
...
it 'returns all car users' do
  FactoryGirl.create(:car_user, rental_user_id: 4, car_id: 2, role: 'rental')
    get :index
    puts response.body
    parsed_response = JSON.parse(response.body)

    expect(parsed_response[0]['id']).to eq(1)
    expect(parsed_response[0]['rental_user_id']).to eq(4)
    expect(parsed_response[0]['car_id']).to eq(2)
    expect(parsed_response[0]['role']).to eq('rental')
end
...
```

I always get the following error:

```
CarUsersController returns all car users
Failure/Error: expect(parsed_response[0]['rental_user_id'].to eq(4)

  expected: 4
       got: nil

  (compared using ==)
```

Comment: What goes outputted from your `puts response.body` line? **EDIT**: your factory doesn't accept a `rental_user` association, that's probably it.  Also you should try to avoid hard coding in your expectations (especially for the model ID). Store the car_user object you get back from the factory and compare against that.

Comment: just [{"id":1}]

Comment: Do you use a serializer?

Comment: @MrDanA: you mean like: car_user = parsed_response and then expect(car_user.rental_user_id).to be(4)?

Comment: @radubogdan oh yes, good point. I created it, but forgot to put in the values... i'm dumb i know ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are not adding the `rental_association` to your factory.

Also, you should avoid hard coding values within your expectations. Instead, you can save the `car_user` instance and compare against that.

```
car_user = FactoryGirl.create(role: "rental", ...)
...
expect(parsed_response[0]['id']).to eq(car_user.id)
expect(parsed_response[0]['role']).to eq(car_user.role)
```

Especially with IDs, they will never always be 1. If your test is run in a different order, and another CarUser is made first, this would always now fail. In addition, if you ever changed a single value of what you sent to the factory, you'd have to then manually change it everywhere. In this situation, for example, if you changed the role to "owner", you now don't have to change your expectation line.